# CC.net & Git operation timeout problem

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

**scenario:**
I have installed msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.3.1-preview20101002 & CruiseControl.Net 1.6.
also i use vs2010 on windows 7.

the configuration file of cc.net looks like below:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
<project name="TestCC.net">
    <sourcecontrol type="git">
        <repository>D:\testcc2\</repository>
        <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
        <timeout>680</timeout>
        <executable>D:\Software\GIT\msysgit\cmd\git.cmd</executable>
        <workingDirectory>D:\testCC.net\</workingDirectory>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger seconds="1200" />
    </triggers>
    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <workingDirectory>D:\testCC.net</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>firsttest.sln</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
            <targets>Clean;Build</targets>
            <timeout>480</timeout>
            <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
        <nunit path="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe">
            <assemblies>
                <assembly>D:\testCC.net\TestSuit\bin\Debug\TestSuit.dll</assembly>
            </assemblies>
        </nunit>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
        <xmllogger />
        <statistics />
    </publishers>
</project>
```

abvoiusly D:\testCC.net\ is the working directory & D:\testcc2\  is the Git's bare repository directory.

the problem is that i create D:\testCC.net\ folder(emoty one). then force the cc.net to start the process with its web dashboard. it creates the .git directory, but get this error:

**ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation has timed out.**

i recheck every thing, but the error is there.
after some try, it checkouts the files.(files created in D:\testCC.net), but the error  is again there.

i opened the solution one time, build it & close. now every thing is good & the green cc.net successfull build message appeared.

why this happens?
is this a problem from cc.net? or my config?

Answer (score 0):

Go to services.msc and restart cruise service, when it starts misbehaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the timeout - it is set for less than a second.